# Is there a performance hit when methods returning JSX are called in render function of React component whenver any state is changed?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

Everytime I type something in input, `state.addTodo` is updated, resulting in calling `render`, which also calls `allTodos` even though it doesn't uses `state.addTodo`. Is this giving a performance hit? If yes how can I fix it?
(Does calling a function in `render` degrading performance or it is not because it is only updating V-DOM and not the DOM?)

Also, is there any easy way to reset a form as well as reset all variables (here only `state.addTodo`) to default values which are associated with that form?

```
class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: {},
    addTodo: ""
  };

  allTodos = () => {
    if(Object.keys(this.state.todos).length === 0)
      return null;
    const jsx = Object.keys(this.state.todos).map(timestamp => (
      <li key={timestamp}>{this.state.todos[timestamp].todo}</li>
    ));
    return jsx;
  };

  onSubmitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const timestamp = Date.now()*10000 + Math.random()*10000;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      todos: {...prevState.todos, 
        [timestamp]: {
          todo: prevState.addTodo,
          done: false
        }
      },
      addTodo: ""
    }));
    e.target.reset();
  };

  onChangeHandler = e => {
    const name= e.target.name, value = e.target.value;
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      [name]: value
    }));
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>All todos</h3>
        <ul>{this.allTodos()}</ul>

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <input type="text" name="addTodo" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in noticing that all of the todos are being re-rendered even when you don't make changes to state.todos. If you don't want to re-render those todos, you can make make an entirely new component that just renders those todos. EX:

```
const TodoList = ({ todos }) => {
  if(Object.keys(todos).length === 0)
      return null;
  const todoList = Object.keys(todos).map(timestamp => (
    <li key={timestamp}>{todos[timestamp].todo}</li>
  ));
  return todoList;
}

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    todos: {},
    addTodo: ""
  };

  ...other handlers are the same

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>All todos</h3>
        <ul><TodoList todos={this.state.todos} /></ul>

        <form onSubmit={this.onSubmitHandler}>
          <input type="text" name="addTodo" onChange={this.onChangeHandler}/>
          <button type="submit">Add</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

This is a very common case for React and is exactly why React is considered 'compositional'. Now that the todos are in a new component, React can tell that the props (`todos`) for the component have not changed and they will not be re-rendered.

As far as your second question, if you want to reset more than one variable you can always call setState with default values for those variables.

EX:

```
this.setState({
    todos: {},
    addTodo: "",
})
```

Comment: Does calling a function in `render` degrading performance or it is not because it is only updating V-DOM and not the DOM?

Comment: Calling render without the extra component updates the virtual dom and the DOM because React thinks the todos need to be re-rendered. To React, using a single class for both means their is only one v-dom node and it thinks it should re-render.